# Need to resize height of card in Banno

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Setting up a card in Banno allows for setting up an "Initial height" for a Card in pixels; but there is no way I am aware of as to how to change it dynamically. As this is a huge issue, with cards widths being dynamic and with different platforms like mobile and desktop. The amount of empty space or something cropped out all together in one profile or another or in multiple cases... this is an issue. Found other postings with info about using the banno-bridge and have used that for link related items that needed special handling; but would need more details and info, if the bridge can help in this regard as hinted.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

It's not possible to dynamically change the height of a plugin's Card Face at runtime. The height of a plugin's Card Face is statically configurable at configuration time per https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/.

In terms of varying widths across platforms/devices, per https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/:

> Plugins should be designed to be responsive and adapt to a variety of screen sizes to accommodate a great user experience for both Banno Mobile and Banno Online users.

### Longer answer

The Plugin Bridge does not have the ability to change the height of a plugin's Card Face.

However, what it *does* have the ability to do is [activate the Expanded View](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face). That's not exactly the same thing as dynamically updating the height of a plugin's Card Face, but it *does* have a somewhat similar effect i.e. the user has more *room* to maneuver in the UI in the [Expanded View](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#expanded-view).